# Data cut off during $_POST Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem is with the following $_POST request. The issue is that I am $_POSTing an array with 855 records via AJAX, but my AJAX controller is only receiving 833. It's always the same records received, and it always cuts out at the same point:

JQuery:

```
var f = {};
f.chargeID = chargeID;
f.method = 'saveIndividualApplications';
f.individualAmounts = individualAmts;

processing.show();

console.log(f); //all records present
console.log(Object.keys(f.individualAmounts).length); //855

return $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    url: appControllerPath,
    data: f
});
```

PHP controller:

```
$displayMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size'); //125912
file_put_contents('post', $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] . "\r\n"); //240M (increased this to 240 just to check)
file_put_contents('post', $displayMaxSize . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('post', print_r($_SERVER, true), FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('post', count($_POST['individualAmounts']) . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND); //833
file_put_contents('post', print_r($_POST['individualAmounts'], true), FILE_APPEND); // data cuts off midway through 833rd record (although the array seems to close fine)
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of timeout enabled?

Comment: @Script47 Not that this request would be hitting, no. There is no processing done between these two points - literally just send and receive. It's completed very quickly (few seconds).

Comment: What's the unit type of the post max size?

Comment: @HenriSchellingerhout I didn't set a flag, so bytes (yes?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be limited by `max_input_vars` config option, by default it's limited to 1000. Inroduced in 5.3.9, check the [PHP runtime config](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php)

Or if you are using [Suhosin](http://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html) it may by limited by it

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
```

Comment: This is correct - thank so much, I would never have found it. Had it at 2500, so bumped it to 3500 and all records came through.

Comment: Worth noting that `max_input_vars` cannot be modified by `ini_set()`